# Implicitly checking if axios call was success

Tags: javascript, axios

Imagine in my app I have:

```
   let res = await axios({
        url: 'https://test.com/posts/1',
        method: 'get',
        timeout: 8000,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })

    console.log("Success");
```

So you can see that I don't manually check the response status code of above call, rather assume that if `"Success"` was printed on console, the above call was success, otherwise there would be an exception or promise rejection and JS wouldn't continue till `console.log`.

Is this safe assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `axios` throws an error for non `2xx` responses, so you can assume success at the point of your `console.log`. You'll of course want to catch errors and handle appropriately so you don't have an unhandled rejection issue.

If you don't want this behavior, you can use the [`validateStatus` config option](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

Comment: I see, but if further error handling isn't needed (e.g. I sometimes report errors using axios interceptors), I can as well leave it like that, without a `try` - and assume success at log...

Answer (score 4):

check response using `if (response.status == 200)`. However for non 2XX response, axios will automatically handle this.

```
axios.get(url, config)
.then(function(res) {
  // successful response flow
})
.catch(function(error) {
  // error response flow
})
```